# Display data from postgis over google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, vector, kml, postgis, spatial

I am working on a project where i am using postgres/postgis and asp.net with c# connected with google maps api v3.

My issue is that i would like to be able to display spatial data ex: points of interests from the db on the map.

Is there exists any library that will do the conversion from postgis to a format like .kml?

Answer (score 2):

There is a wrapper called [as_kmldoc](http://blog.mackerron.com/2010/09/29/as_kmldoc/) for PostGIS' `ST_AsKML` function, you could give it a try. It is not really sophisticated but could suit your needs.

```
SELECT as_kmldoc(osgb_location, NAME, code) FROM wunderground_stations;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ST_AsKML but then you still need to create the KML string using that data. Here is the full function (in php), which creates kml with world borders from mysql database.

```
public function generateWorld() {

    $tolerance = 20000;

    $select = $this->_db->select()
        ->from ( array( 'w' => 'world_borders'),
                array ('cat', 'cntry_name', 'geom' => "ST_AsKML(transform(ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology(transform(w.the_geom, 2249), " . $tolerance . "),4326))"));
    $result = $this->_db->fetchAll($select);

    $countriesByCat = array();
    foreach ($result as $r) {
        if ($countriesByCat[$r['cat']] === null) $countriesByCat[$r['cat']] = array();
        array_push($countriesByCat[$r['cat']], $r);
    }

    $kml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
        <Document>
            <name>borders</name>';

    for($i = 0; $i < count($countriesByCat); $i++) {
        $kml .= '<Placemark><name>'.$countriesByCat[$i][0]['cntry_name'].'</name>';
            if (count($countriesByCat[$i]) > 1) {
            $kml .= '<MultiGeometry>';
            foreach ($countriesByCat[$i] as $geom) {
                $kml .= $geom['geom'];
            }
            $kml .= '</MultiGeometry>';
        }
        else {
            $kml .= $countriesByCat[$i][0]['geom'];
        }

        $kml .= '</Placemark>';
    }

    $kml .= '</Document></kml>';

    echo $kml;
}
```